# Expected Power Product of rolling a dice .

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math, expectation, multinomial-coefficients

A 15 sided dice is rolled 1000 times.
Let k1,k2,k3,k4,..k15 denote the number of times 1,2,3...15 appears.

How can I compute the following expected value :$$E( (k_1 k_2 k_3 k_4)^5).$$

My attempts::
I tried using multinomial theorem , then using  the moment-generating function  and then the stirling numbers but failed miserably.

Edit: Note that I was able to find $E( (k_1 k_2 k_3 k_4))$, a general formula in terms of falling factorial but not any further .

Comment: The answer is:

$$\frac{1613937892509777463663401881757759967007670132416848}{360406494140625} \approx 4.48\times 10^{36}$$

Comment: @d.k.o. Thankss a ton man . How did you compute that , using a random function or is there some technical method ? Please describe the approach if it`s not by rand() .

Comment: Actually, it' similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351020/expected-value-when-die-is-rolled-n-times/1351043#1351043

Comment: To be compared with the Poisson approximation $$(E(X^5))^4,$$ with $X$ Poisson of parameter $1000/15$, which leads in one line of calculus to the approximated value $$5.364\times10^{36}.$$

Comment: @d.k.o. Yeah I see that , it is much general though thanks.So in general case we can`t really simplify the formula much. 
Btw reading there,answers and comments , I realise we can simplify calculations 1-2 steps to significantlly reduce the number of operations  computationally if we assume L,L*F much smaller than N,K , variable names from there . 
This is because each of the pi is equal and sum to one . So differentiating and multiplying(which will not change the degree=N) would render few terms with different coefficients compared to terms in your general formula.