# Finding the Expected Value of Two discrete Random Variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Problem:
Suppose that a $3$ sided dice is thrown $n$ times.  Let $d_1$ be the number
of times the number $1$ comes up.  Let $d_2$ be the number of times the
number $2$ comes up. What is the expected value of $d_1 d_2$?
Answer:
For the special case of $n = 1$, $E(d_1 d_2) = 0$. Now, for the general case.
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(d_1 d_2) &=&
    \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n-i}
        { i(j) P( d_1 = i ) P ( d_2 = j | d_1 = i ) }  \\
P( d_1 = i ) &=&  {{n}\choose{i}} (\frac{1}{3})^{i} (\frac{2}{3})^{n-i} \\
P ( d_2 = j | d_1 = i ) &=&
    {{n - i}\choose{j}} (\frac{1}{2})^{j} (\frac{1}{2})^{n-i-j} \\
E(d_1 d_2) &=&
    \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n-i}
        { i(j) P( d_1 = i ) {{n - i}\choose{j}} (\frac{1}{2})^{j} (\frac{1}{2})^{n-i-j} } \\
E(d_1 d_2) &=&
    \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n-i}
        { i(j)  {{n}\choose{i}} (\frac{1}{3})^{i} (\frac{2}{3})^{n-i} {{n - i}\choose{j}} (\frac{1}{2})^{j} (\frac{1}{2})^{n-i-j} } \\
E(d_1 d_2) &=&
    \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n-i}
        { i(j)  {{n}\choose{i}} (\frac{1}{3})^{i} (\frac{2}{3})^{n-i} {{n - i}\choose{j}} (\frac{1}{2})^{n-i} } \\
E(d_1 d_2) &=&
    \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n-i}
        { i(j)  {{n}\choose{i}} (\frac{1}{3})^{i} (\frac{1}{3})^{n-i} {{n - i}\choose{j}} } \\
E(d_1 d_2) &=&
    \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n-i}
        { i(j)  {{n}\choose{i}} (\frac{1}{3})^{n} {{n - i}\choose{j}} } \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Is this right so far? How do I finish the problem?

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}j\binom{n-i}{j}=2^{n-i-1}(n-i).
$$
Then
$$
\frac{1}{3^n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{n-i}j\binom{n-i}{j}=\frac{n(n-1)}{3^n}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-2}{i-1}2^{n-i-1}=\frac{1}{9}n(n-1).
$$

---

The first equality follows from the binomial theorem because
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y)^{n-i}\Big|_{x=1,y=1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-i} j\binom{n-i}{j}
$$

Comment: d.k.o., I do not understand how you come up with your first equation. I am talking about the one whose right hand side is: $2^{n-i-1}(n-i)$.

Comment: @Bob I added some details.

Comment: @Bob Here is the link for a more general question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351020/expected-value-when-die-is-rolled-n-times/1351043#1351043

Comment: Now, I understand how you got the first equation. However, I am confused about the second equation. Could you put in more detail there also? Thank you very much. Bob.

Comment: @Bob use the binomial theorem, i.e. $(1+2)^{n-2}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}2^{n-k-2}$ and set $i=k+1$...